# How to implement bi-directional scroll in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, scrollview, flutter-layout, bidirectional

Is there any way I can make a screen scroll in multiple directions smoothly? It would be really helpful if someone who has already done it would share how. I've tried using the plugin - https://pub.dev/packages/bidirectional_scroll_view#-analysis-tab-
but it doesn't work smoothly, and is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

Read the issue at https://github.com/toufikzitouni/flutter-bidirectional_scrollview_plugin/issues/4

It recommends to add Silvers as the plugin is not implementing recycler.

Comment: That was an old issue, plugin has been updated with adding slivers.

Comment: Don't know about details as the issue is still left open.